# Chrome crashes on loading serviceworker for localhost

Tags: google-chrome, crash, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

Using [Workbox's Get Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started), I have recently gotten a service worker working on my webapp. However, after adding networkFirst, the app did not register any cached js. However, the service worker needed to be restarted and reloaded before any logs showed up in the console.

After adding CSS caching, when I load my webapp in Chrome using localhost, it crashes. **The app does not crash Firefox**.

I've [posted this to bug reports](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933489&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=) (sw.js file posted there) but thought I'd try here in case anyone has experiences and solved this, or it's an issue with my files or file structure.

```
mywebsite
    --/static
        - sw.js
        - index.html
        - main.js
        - manifest.webmanifest
        -- /favicons
            - manifest.json
```

Comment: To make the bug report actionable you'll need to provide a way to run the test case easily e.g. attach a zip with the necessary files and describe the exact sequence of actions to perform e.g. "unzip, open console, run npm install, run npm start"

Comment: Filed a bug report, it's magically working this morning with no changes on my end. Will update once I hear back from Chromium. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933489#c6